# Cannot open existing or create new SQL Server Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

PLEASE HELP!!!!

**MY SET UP**

Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Update 4 on Windows 7 Professional,

**ACTION**

Installed latest SQL Server Data Tools Update

**SYMPTOM 1 (Cannot create)**

When attempting to create new project, I get:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.11, Version=11.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The System cannot find the file specified.

**SYMPTOM 2 (Cannot open existing project)**

When attempting to open an existing project, I get:

> Unsupported
>
> This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project
>   types installed or does not support them. You can still open these
>   projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally
>   created.
>
> Non-functional changes required
>
> Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the
>   following projects in order to enable them to open in this version and
>   Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- I have uninstalled/reinstalled VS2012, SSDT, and Update 4.
- I've gone through "Programs and Features" Control Panel and have Repaired everything in several different orders.
- I have been all over the internet and have tried every single workaround from every article even remotely related to my situation, including deleting temporary files, registry keys, etc.

Nothing seems to work.

Please help me, I'm on day 2 of being dead in the water.

Answer (score 2):

MICROSOFT -- HEADS UP!!!

This appears to have worked !!!!

1. Zip up the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
   Server\110\DAC\bin and set aside (in case this doesn't work for you)
2. Delete the contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin
3. Copy the entire contents of

   C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120

   into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin`
4. Re-launch VS2012,

AND

- I was able to create a new SQL Server Database Project, and
- I was able to open one of my existing projects.

VS did crash once when i was looking through my project using the SQL Server Object Explorer, but I have not been able to duplicate it.